Cant config Vercel to accept payload more than 100MB
I'm trying to do something weird I know, but not that weird that the issue with allowing the Vercel to accept more than 100MB of body payload. I know this is not practical for most cases, but why:
module.exports = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '200mb'
        }
    }
}

Doesn't seem to allow the send of 100MB
nor
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '200mb'
        }
    }
}

Doesn't allow me to request to Vercel more than 4 MB ( I think)
Error message: 413 Payload Too Large
I use normal API ROUTES

Or is there a way to totally disable this limit, because Vercel calculates bandwidth, so why they care if a request of mine is 1GB at all

Check https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/solutions/aws-s3-image-upload.
Better to upload to your storage directly than passing big files to Vercel's servers.

@paulogdm im not uploading photos rather data so this is why i asked that

What is the difference? Why would you treat data different from a photo? Everything can be a file after all... I am not sure if I follow.

Even if you need to process this data, you may want to hold it in a bucket, not in the server directly. Despite that, given the usage, I would recommend an API hosted in Railway while keeping your frontend on Vercel. That way, you will have more flexibility manipulating that much data.
